# dbeaver community version cannot dump database

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I really hope someone will be able to help me. a new debian 12 installation, with latest dbeaver community installed to maintain various network databases.

in order fro dbeaver dump to work had to install mariadb-client locally on the laptop in order to get mysqldump and be able to configure localclient section of the dbeaver (previous versions did not require that)

The primary issue is that I cannot dump databases. The error that I am  getting: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'select column_name, extra, generation_expression, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_schema=database() and table_name=table_name order by ordinal_position': Unknown column 'generation_expression' in 'field list' (1054)

so after some searching it seems that the issue is column-statistics.

I sense that I missing something really basic, but cannot figure out what I need to do. Is this a mismatch between dbeaver and mysqldump, or is it a mismatch between locally installed mariadb-client and the actual sql server?

debeaver version 24.0.1
mysqldump version from mariadb-client is 1:10.11.6-0+deb12u1

please push me in the right direction. Thank you in advance for any pointers

what I have tried:

1. tried adding the switch [mysqldump] column-statistics=0, but this gives me an error mysqldump: unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'
2. tried running the command in the terminal to dump the database the same issue.